# Problem syncing phone with Outlook

Tags: sync, outlook, lumia-535

I am having problems syncing my Lumia 535 with Outlook. The problem started more than 9 months ago. I get error code 80070057. As well as I tried to syncing new email account and I was unable to do that.

Answer (score 1):

did you read this explanation?

https://www.qbgarage.com/what-does-error-code-80070057-mean/

and try this solution next to understanding your problem

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-install-updates-error-code-80070057/680c0cd4-ba4e-4cb3-9a22-801632bd460c

Comment: Can you provide a summary of the links in your answer? Link-only answers can become useless if the linked page ever changes or goes offline.